# Video's suddenly stopped playing from Youtube API

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

We've been using the Youtube API in our Android Application for about 3 months now, we removed alot of old video's the last couple of days and updated our MYSQL server where the video ID's are stored.

We made 60 video's add dynamically (using the MYSQL) in our main screen, and i've added about 6 video's 'hardcoded', so nothing should have gone wrong there.

Suddenly all the video's won't play inside the application and give the error "There was a problem while playing, touch to retry". I can keep tapping but nothing happens. I do see that it is loading the right video.

If I keep tapping the bottom right corner, where the link to the youtube web/app is, then it will load the video inside the normal youtube application. It is working fine inside the normal Youtube App.

### What I tried so far:

- Restarted my device
- Uninstall my application and installing it again
- Switch from WiFi to 3G
- Tested a friends phone who also has the application
- Generating a new Youtube_API_KEY and adding it to the application
- Tried multiple Youtube accounts, even tested without being logged into Youtube

None of the above mentioned attempts worked. 
Does anyone mayby has a clue where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8091) earlier with the YouTube API, and the bug was introduced with a specific version of the **YouTube app**. That is, the presence of the bug in my application depended on the installed version of YouTube.

If you go to `Settings` > `Apps` > `YouTube`, tap `Uninstall Updates`, you can install another version of YouTube directly with an .apk file downloaded from [here](http://www.androidapksfree.com/version-history/youtube-apk-version-history/), for example.

Install an **earlier version** of YouTube for a temporary solution. You may want to raise an issue [at the issue tracker for YouTube](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list), and wait for the fix.

Comment: You may also need to disable `Auto-update apps` in the Settings of Google Play to prevent it from updating YouTube to the latest version.

Comment: Hmmmm...This solution did work, but i'm not happy with this because I cannot force all my users to uninstall all their Youtube updates. Thanks for sharing that link (and the solution ofcoure), i'll post an issue there, hope they will look after it soon.

Comment: Yes, this is not a proper solution for many users. I'm also suggesting that you might not be able to fix this in your code, but Google might be able to fix it in the code of YouTube.

Comment: We just noticed that it only happens on video's from our channel. We checked with a different channel and the video's worked?! Mayby a solution to start a new channel?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, I haven't encountered an issue like that yet. Starting a new channel sounds reasonable. Does the problem persist on a phone with a clean install of YouTube? (where you're not logged in as the owner of that channel)

Comment: Even when i'm logged in as the user who has the video's on that channel, the problem persists. But when I remove all the updates from my Android device, it is fixed. So Youtube should have blocked our video's for external apps, they do work in the normal youtube app though. I think i'll just make a new youtube channel. Thanks for the help, i'll give this awnser the solution since we cannot fix this problem ourselfs... If somebody reads this later on, i'd still like to know what an other solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such a problem, some videos can be played only in the YouTube player. To circumvent this problem, we had to pump out all the videos from youtube and use the id of the video.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this code snippet

```
 /**
 * Method used to play video in a new activity
 *
 * @param context the activity context
 * @param url     the url of the youtube video to be played
 */
public static void playVideo(Context context, String url) {

    String ytId = extractYTId(url);
    if (ytId != null && ytId != "") {
        Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) context, DEVELOPER_KEY, ytId, 0, false, false);
        context.startActivity(videoIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "this is not youtube url!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

you just have to add youtube Api **.jar** and call this method then hope so your video will play..

enjoy your code time:)

Answer (score -1):

If you go to Settings > Apps > YouTube, tap Uninstall Updates, you can install another version of YouTube directly with a .apk file downloaded from [here](https://likertools.blogspot.com/2020/01/microsoft-maths-solver.html) for example.

Comment: The described issue belongs to the developer's app not YouTube's one.