# YouTube Android Player API is not working in xiaomi Redmi Note 3

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, redmi-device, xiaomi

YouTube Android Player API is not working. It is worked for only one time and second time onwards showing this error `Please check your network connection Tap to retry`

I checked my network connection it is working fine. I tested various samples and creating various android key's in google console.

**Steps to Reproduce**

We can able to reproduce this issue in google sample application give for YouTube Android Player API

1. Download the sample app from this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)
2. Update you DEVELOPER_KEY in DeveloperKey.java
3. Run the app and play the video in Simple Player View it plays for now.
4. Again try to play the same now it showing an error.
5. But I checked in log it showing this `Forcefully created
   overlay:abaa@d131896 helper:Lazy@ca35c17 view:null status: ......
   {...}`

I am struggling how to resolve this? Is this any library issue from google? Is any answer to solve this issue? 
Your help is appreciated.

[image: screen shot]

**EDIT**

> I found this issue facing only in xiaomi phones it seems.  I am using
>   xiaomi Redmi Note 3, from this device only error occurs

Comment: share your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027416/videos-suddenly-stopped-playing-from-youtube-api) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843919/getting-error-there-was-a-issue-with-network-400-while-playing-you-tube-vide)

Comment: @Hemant You can download from this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: @HemantParmar Its not exact problem of that question how can you say its duplicated?

Comment: does xiaomi phones support google play services ? if not , then you tube player can not be integrated in those devices

Comment: @AdeelTurk, The device is support google play service, and it has youtube player app and I checked for update and it also upto date.

Comment: The current implementation of the YouTube player from Google is known for being not exactly the best library. I've been working on my own open source implementation to use as a replacement for the official library. If you're working with YouTube maybe it can come handy to you as well. https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Comment: @PierfrancescoSoffritti Thanks for your suggestion. But Its miracle and it is working fine now in Xiaomi devices

Answer (score 0):

Just add ONLY your youtube ID and it works FINE!!!!

Nikolas